# Input string was not in a correct format error on changing server machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, webforms, int

I have this code to parse `Int` from `String` like this: *560,000*

```
int.Parse(myTextBox.Text.Trim(), NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

it works properly on my local machine but when I install my web application on another server with same *web.config* culture as this :

```
<globalization culture="fa-IR" uiCulture="fa-IR" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

this error occurs:

> Input string was not in a correct format

My local machine .NET version: *Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929*

My new server .NET version: *Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408*

Comment: Check which process your int.Parse is being executed in (it may not be the process which owns the web.config). Check the culture of the current thread using System.Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect culture specific format for input simply pass it as argument to [Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yaffedz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int.Parse(myTextBox.Text.Trim(), 
      NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
      new CultureInfo("fa-IR"));
```

Note that you'd better use user's culture rather than hard-coding one you like if you site can be visited from multiple locales.

Comment: same error. no thing changed! thank you for your answer.